# Recover item deleted with parentNode.removeChild

Tags: javascript, recovery, removechild, parent-node

Do you know how I could recover an item deleted with JavaScript in the following way:

```
elem1.parentNode.removeChild(elem1);
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Unless you store the *element* as a variable before you delete it.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it automatically. If you need to recover them, your script has to remember them itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the **[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild)** `removeChild` will return a reference to the removed child node. Usage like this:

```
var oldChild = element.removeChild(child);
element.removeChild(child);
```

Further:

> The removed child node still exists in memory, but is no longer part
>   of the DOM. You may reuse the removed node later in your code, via the
>   oldChild object reference.

Answer (score 2):

Without storing the element in a variable prior to deleting it, you can't undo a `removeChild()` call. Calling the function on its own without an assignment will completely remove it from the DOM **and** memory.

You can force JavaScript to store it in memory for use / restoration later by doing this:

```
var restoration_element = elem1.parentNode.removeChild(elem1);
```

Using the latter syntax with an assignment operator will remove the element `elem1` from the display list, but keep it as a reference for use later.

Comment: And the reuse how it could be? With elem1.parentNode.appendChild(restoration_element);     Thank you!!

Comment: Exactly. No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to not only get a reference for the deleted node, but also insert the deleted node back to the same location it was deleted from. As such, I had to use a stack like so:

```
// Note: This is ES6; for ES5 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23528539/2065702
const stack = [];
function removeWithStack() {
    const elem = this,
          parent = elem.parentNode;
    
    const action = {
        "index": Array.from(parent.children).indexOf(elem),
        "parent": parent,
        "elem": parent.removeChild(elem)
    }
    
    stack.push(action);
}

function popAddStack() {
    const action = stack.pop();
    action.parent.insertBefore(action.elem, action.parent.children[action.index]);
}
```

```js
const ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");

// Note: This is ES6; for ES5 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23528539/2065702
const stack = [];
function removeWithStack() {
    const elem = this,
          parent = elem.parentNode;

    const action = {
        "index": Array.from(parent.children).indexOf(elem),
        "parent": parent,
        "elem": parent.removeChild(elem)
    }

    stack.push(action);
}

function popAddStack() {
    const action = stack.pop();
    action.parent.insertBefore(action.elem, action.parent.children[action.index]);
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = popAddStack;

ps.forEach(function(p) {
    p.onclick = removeWithStack;
});
```

```css
button,
p {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <p>Test 2</p>
    <p>Test 3</p>
    <p>Test 4</p>
    <p>Test 5</p>
</div>
<button>Undo</button>
```