# Trouble getting the index of a child when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the index of a child within a parent element. I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913984/3273967), but ended up with an infinite loop.

My code so far:

```
var div = document.getElementById("spans");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var span = e.target;
    var spanSiblings = 0;

    while((span.previousElementSibling) != null ) {
        spanSiblings++;
    }

    console.log(spanSiblings);
});
```

The aim is to output 0 when the user clicks on the first span because it's the first child in the "spans" id:

```
<div id="spans">
    <span>This is span #1</span>
    <span>This is span #2</span>
    <span>This is span #3</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not changing the `span` variable in the loop, the condition will always be the same. If you assign the previous sibling to the variable, then it works:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("spans");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var span = e.target;
    var spanSiblings = 0;

    while((span = span.previousElementSibling) != null ) {
        spanSiblings++;
    }

    console.log(spanSiblings);
});
```

```html
<div id="spans">
    <span>This is span #1</span>
    <span>This is span #2</span>
    <span>This is span #3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing a little from jQuery, which checks the elements position with `$.inArray` in it's `index` function, you can do

```
var div = document.getElementById("spans");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var span  = e.target;
    var arr   = [].slice.call(spans);
    var index = arr.indexOf( span );

    console.log( index );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/z2xczfv2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your while loop condition. You don't have any condition to terminate the while loop. Change your while loop code to

```
while((span = span.previousElementSibling) != null ) {
    spanSiblings++;
}
```