# Why does window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("order") doesn't returns order of a flexbox element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

From [**MDN Web Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle): "**`window.getComputedStyle()`** method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain."

`Window.getComputedStyle()` returns a **`CSSStyleDeclaration`** object which contains key-value pairs containing names of all the CSS properties. To get the resolved value of a particular CSS property, **`getPropertyValue("property-name")`** can be used. But, `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".box1")).getPropertyValue("order")` is returning the order of element w/ class `.box1` in the flexbox as "0". Infact, it's returning the order of every element inside flexbox as "0".

Link to **JS Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/asxyzp/h6b3j5dL/

**Additional context**: I was trying to add tooltip to my project (https://flexgrid.asxyzp.repl.co/ref?platform=so), using tippy.js which creates a tooltip for every flexbox element using ``` tippy('.box1',{content:``CLASS: .box1, ORDER : ${window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".box1")).getPropertyValue("order")}``}); ``` so that it would display the order of the flexbox element dynamically, even when changes are made, but it didn't work, so I tried to do it in fiddle, but even there I was getting the order for elements as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `order` css rule on the element,

Try adding:

```
.box3 {
  order: 1;
}
```

or:

```
.box1 { order: 1 }
.box2 { order: 2 }
.box3 { order: 3 }
.box4 { order: 4 }
```

[image: fiddle]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg3ocbxj/1/)

Order property is 0 by default
when there are multiple flex children
with the same order
they are displayed by their order in the DOM (or HTML).

Comment: Question: When we do "display: flex;" for the container then aren't all the items, assigned an order w/ increasing value (e.g. 1,2,3,4)? I thought that this happens by default for the flexbox container.

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi no, they all default to 0; also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5913927/13449712