# return the index of childnode when clicked

Tags: javascript, indexing, onclick, child-nodes

**Here, I have** parent div of class = "alphabets" and have child div's all with same class = "word"

```
<div class="alphabets">
  <div class="word"> abc </div> //1st child
  <div class="word"> def </div> //2nd child
  <div class="word"> ghi </div> //3rd child
  <div class="word"> jkl </div> //4th child
  <div class="word"> mno </div> //5th child
</div>
```

**what I need** is When I clicked on 'jkl'. fun() should return its index i.e whether it is 1st child or 2ndchild or 6th child...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913927/get-child-node-index

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` on the `children` (after converting it to an array) of the parent element.

```js
document.querySelector('.alphabets').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.target.matches('.word')) console.log([...this.children].indexOf(e.target));
});
```

```html
<div class="alphabets">
  <div class="word"> abc (1st child)</div>
  <div class="word"> def (2nd child)</div>
  <div class="word"> ghi (3rd child)</div>
  <div class="word"> jkl (4th child)</div>
  <div class="word"> mno (5th child)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: does, " this " indicates  ` document.querySelector('.alphabets') ` ? here

Comment: @CoodingSpace Yes.